# SUM values from given month + previous month

Tags: sql, oracle

Using SQL oracle.
I tried searching, but couldn't find any solution to this particular problem.

I need to sum the amounts from "this month" + "the previous month" over longer periods.

With this query:

```
SELECT
  to_char(sales_date, 'YYYYMM') date,
  count(*) amount

FROM sales
  WHERE sales_date > sysdate-90

  GROUP BY to_char(sales_date, 'YYYYMM')
  ORDER BY to_char(sales_date, 'YYYYMM') desc
```

It gives me a result like this:

```
DATE    AMOUNT
202104  55
202103  12
202102  46
202101  31
```

I am looking for this result:

```
DATE    AMOUNT
202104  67 (Sales from april + march)
202103  58 (Sales from march + february)
202102  77 (Sales from february + january)
202101  31 (plus whatever the sales were in december 2020)
And so on
```

I am drawing a complete blank on how I can accomplish this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
SELECT date, amount + LAG(amount, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY date) 
FROM (SELECT to_char(s.sales_date, 'YYYYMM') as date,
             count(*) as amount
      FROM sales s
      GROUP BY to_char(s.sales_date, 'YYYYMM')
     ) s
WHERE date > sysdate-90
ORDER BY date desc;
```

I would also recommend `add_months()` instead of 90 days, but that is your business logic.

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm. Thank you! And the actual query does not use sysdate-90, this was just to illustrate.